# testing a page served by a route in Node.js with Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am very new to testing and was wondering if I'm on the right track here.

Basically I want to check that my server will serve a specific index.ejs file at a certain route. Here are my two it blocks.

```
it('should respond with status 200',function(done){

    request.get(url+'/polls',function(error,response,body){
        expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        done();
    });

});


it('should render the polls.ejs file',function(done){

    request.get(url + '/polls',function(error,response,body){
        expect(body).to.equal('index.ejs')
        done();
    });

});
```

First test passes, the second test doesn't obviously because it is expecting the string `"index.ejs"` as opposed to the parsed HTML file which is what it's getting.

There must be a better way than writing my entire HTML content as a string to pass the test. Please tell me a better way. And also am I on the right track with testing here?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you should test that kind of things, in fact.

Since you are relying on someone else to serve the webpage, it's his job to test that. You only have to test your own logic there.

For example, if you have a route `/add?a=12&b=15`, and this route is meant to output `27` then you should the part of code that is doing the addition. Not the part that is managing the client's request.

I may be wrong (in which case I'll update this answer to say so) but that's how I handle the unit testing for my own website and it's working pretty fine.

Comment: This sounds logical, I was wondering also. I did realise that i can do this using fs but I don't think it is necessary either as I will not have control over it you are right i think. Also 27 not 37 ;)